# Linking scope of loaded symbols when using swig to wrap C++ for python

Tags: swig, dynamic-linking

I have a C++ library that I am wrapping with SWIG to make accessible in python. It is my understanding (from experience) that when SWIG wraps a C++ library in python, upon loading it places the C++ library symbols in a "local" scope. That is - a scope which does not enable future dynamically linked libraries to find the symbols.

(I'm getting this definition of "local" from [man dlopen(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) )

Is there any way to get SWIG to place these symbols into the "global" scope, such that any future dynamically linked libraries can find them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make python `dlopen` shared objects with the `RTLD_GLOBAL` flag by calling [`setdlopenflags`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.setdlopenflags) in `sys`, e.g.:

```
sys.setdlopenflags(dl.RTLD_NOW | dl.RTLD_GLOBAL)
```

before your module is loaded. (There's a [discussion on swig-users](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=ECCF46D3-91ED-4C51-B0C3-DCD681141824@geoffhutchison.net&forum_name=swig-user) about this)

Comment: You can reset it do default afterwards. `dlopen()` is a standard call, internally python *must* be using it to open the shared object for your module. There's a note on the python docs I linked to saying "If DLFCN is not available, it can be generated from /usr/include/dlfcn.h using the h2py script". This is controlling how python internally calls `dlopen()`, not calling it yourself.

Comment: I'll articulate better - upon attempting to load a library with the dl module python raises an error saying that if sizeof(int) != sizeof(void*) then it's not going to let you use dlopen. So it may well be using it, but it's not letting me use it. But will the sys.setdlopenflags work in this case?

Comment: I see what you're asking now. Yes, there's no reason why even with that problem that it shouldn't yet you call `sys.setdlopenflags()` still.

Comment: Cool thanks, I'll go try it out, also thankyou for the discussion link - glad to see I'm not the only one trying this.